# Expanding 1D array into multidimensional array using np.repeat

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1D array `A` of shape: `(35,)`, 
and I want to create from it an array `B` of shape: `(500,35,14,56)`
in a way that it will repeat itself `500*14*56` times. 
so `A[1] = B[0][1][0][0] = B[1][1][1][1] ...` etc.
I know I can probably use `np.repeat` to do it, but I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend input to higher dim and then use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) -

```
np.broadcast_to(A[:,None,None], (500,35,14,56))
```

Note that this would be a view into the input. For an output with its own memory space, use [`.copy()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.copy.html).

Comment: Thank you! I tried what you said, but I expected the result of ```B[0][:][0][0]``` give me the values of A, but I get only one of the values from A repeated. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: @ValientProcess Yeah, don't do that. Use the array indexing : `B[0,:,0,0]`.

Comment: Thank you !!! Can you say what's the difference in the indexing?

Comment: @ValientProcess The first one that you suggested doesn't do what you are expecting it to. To understand what's going on, use `a = np.random.rand(2,3,5)` and then do `a[0][:][1]` and then `a[0,:,1]`. It's better to try out for yourself to understand.